# localhost loads wrong version of php

Tags: php, macos

I installed php 5.4 on my macbook pro running 10.8 using Liip's service http://php-osx.liip.ch/#ext:

```
    curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.4
```

I check the php version using Terminal:

```
    php -v
```

and see the correct version of php:

```
PHP 5.4.13 (cli) (built: Mar 18 2013 09:51:28) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.2.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans
```

I uncommented LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so from httpd.conf. However, when I run phpinfo() from localhost, I am running php 5.3. How do I get localhost to run php 5.4?

Comment: Are you sure you restarted the httpd?

Comment: yes, restarted using: sudo apachectl restart

Comment: Is this the first time you've installed PHP on the machine?

Comment: Did you try grepping for the .so module in apache's configuration site? Perhaps there's another entry somewhere there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac's usually come with Apache pre-installed, including an installation of php and mysql, which is configured to localhost.  you need to go reconfig the path to php in the default apache's `httpd.conf` file, or alternatively use PHP 5.4's built in server, which operates on a specific port, which will allow you to use PHP's built in server instead of your Mac's default apache installation.

The PHP manual shows how to start up PHP's built in server on port 8000: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: The second paragraph's pretty interesting!

Comment: Thanks Brian! php -S localhost:8000 in Terminal starts php's server and http://localhost:8000/mylocalDir/ runs it using php 5.4. Nice solution! Do you know whether I can run a local mysql connection with this set-up?

Comment: I haven't done this myself yet, so can't be sure, but if you have a installation of mysql, I believe the 5.4 server supports the PDO object to connect and query on localhost. Run `phpinfo()` on that server to see what extensions it supports.  As long as you have a mysql db built on your local and the 5.4 servers support the right objects/function, you're good to go!